# CMD .bat file include by "sub.bat" vs "CALL sub.bat"

Tags: windows, batch-file, call

I have 2 files `start.bat` and `include.bat` in a directory

```sh
REM include.bat
c:\php\php.exe script.php
```

```sh
@echo off
echo T1
CALL include.bat
echo T2
include.bat
echo T3
```

T3 does not show. `.bat` script dies.
What's the difference between calling bat file directly vs CALL?

Comment: I believe you should run `call /?`

Comment: You can clearly see the difference by your script: the main script `start.bat` passes over execution control to the other batch file `include.bat` but it does not return to the original one without `call`, but it does when using `call`...